# How to dowload this whole "https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-05-01-WebRTCBasic" without using any extra software?

Tags: github

I want to download a single folder in Github https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-05-01-WebRTCBasic.

However, there is no download button in that folder.. I heard other people said using svn stuffs like that but I do not know what it is and I do not want to use it.

So, How to download the above folder in Github without having to install any software or learn any commands (eg, a normal web user can download it)?

Comment: Go to https://github.com/XSockets/XVA and click at the right bottom button called Download Zip. It will download the whole project.

Comment: If you don't want to "learn any commands", I'm not sure StackOverflow is the right site for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to download a specific folder from GitHub. However, if you want to download the latest version of the project including all folders, visit [the repository's main page](https://github.com/XSockets/XVA) and click the "Download Zip" button on the right hand side of the page.

This will download the latest revision of the `master` branch as a zip file, and then you can unzip it and pick out the specific folder you want.